# Snake game c++ tail class how to add new object

Tags: c++, class, console

i'm a beginner programmer of c++ and i would like some help to continue my snake project.
For making a bit of practice with classes i decided to this program using them to not take the  bad habit of use things like hundreads of functions that can be sintethyzed.

My problem comes when i have to make the tail for my snake because for making it with classes i would need a sort of command that "summons" a new tail object in the program.

for example: my head just collided with food and the tail has got to grow, but 
                            how can i summon a new tail object??

here is the code (i will work soon on removing system("cls") later to make the program run smoother):

::::::::::::::::SNAKE.cpp:::::::::::::::::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include "Head.h"


int score = 0;


int main()
{
    HEAD head;


    while (1)
    {
        head.key();
        head.movement();
        head.show();

        if (GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        Sleep(100);
        system("cls");
    }

}
```

:::::::::::::HEAD.h:::::::::::::

```
#include <iostream>

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

class HEAD
{

private:
    int x = 20;
    int y = 20;
    int direction, lastdirection;


public:

    void show()
    {
        gotoxy(x, y); std::cout << "@";
    }

    void movement()
    {
        lastdirection = direction;

        switch (direction)
        {
        case 1:
            y--;
            break;
        case 2:
            x--;
            break;
        case 3:
            y++;
            break;
        case 4:
            x++;
            break;
        }

    }
    void key()
    {
        //------------directions-----------

        if (GetKeyState('W') & 0x8000)
        {
            direction = 1;
        }

        if (GetKeyState('A') & 0x8000)
        {
            direction = 2;
        }

        if (GetKeyState('S') & 0x8000)
        {
            direction = 3;
        }

        if (GetKeyState('D') & 0x8000)
        {
            direction = 4;
        }

        //-------specific direction changes--------

        if (lastdirection == 1 && direction == 3 || lastdirection == 3 && direction == 1)
        {
            direction = lastdirection;
        }

        if (lastdirection == 2 && direction == 4 || lastdirection == 4 && direction == 2)
        {
            direction = lastdirection;
        }


    }

};
```

i hope that you can help me because this is a project that need to finish because for me it is the hardest thing i've ever programmed in c++ (after pong)

Comment: Try creating a class `Tail` or `TailSegment` or ehatever. Then you can add an `std::vector<TailSegment>` to the head class which is a dynamically allocated array so you can insert TailSegments as you want. Then add a `AddTailSegment` Method to your head and call it when you pick up a piece of food. In your `Head::show` you then simply iterate over the tail segments and print them to their position.

Comment: Also mind that this question might rather go to [Software engeneering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: or here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RyanN1220 possibly but this question has more to do with code design and coding solutions than with game design if you ask me.

Comment: @Yastanub ok i see, but i still do not fully comprehend how i should with that vector. can you make me an example please? or can you give me something like a youtube video where someone explains it clearly?

Comment: @Sir.Rosticciano i'd like to help you but here is not the proper place. Come and join [a chat room for this discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184091/room-for-sir-rosticciano-and-yastanub)